# $\beta(B)\subseteq C(X)$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

See the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542545/every-banach-space-is-isometric-to-a-subspace-of-cx-for-some-compact-space).

I'm struggling to show that $\beta(B)\subseteq C(X)$ is closed.

Here $B$ is a Banach space, $X$ is the closed unit ball in the dual space $B^{*}$ with the weak-star topology and $\beta:B \rightarrow C(X)$ such that $\beta(f)(\phi) = \phi (f)$ for each $\phi\in X$ and each $f \in B$.

I know that $\beta$ is linear, injective, and an isometry (and therefore also continuous/bounded). Also, $C(X)$ is a Banach space with the uniform norm.

There is a result that states that if $\beta(B)$ is a finite-codimensional subspace of $C(X)$, then $\beta(B)$ is closed. Not sure if it's applicable here.

Comment: $B$ is a complete metric space, and if you already know $\beta$ is an isometry it follows that $\beta(B)$ is a complete metric space.  A subset of a metric space that is complete as a metric space is closed.

Comment: @ChadK That was easy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta(f_n)=\Gamma\in C(X)$. We want to show $\Gamma$ is in the image of $\beta$.

Suppose the $(f_n)_n$ converge to some $f\in B$, in either the strong or weak topologies. Then easily $\Gamma=\beta(f)$ would hold. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and suppose $N\in\Bbb N$ is so large that $\|\beta(f_n)-\beta(f_m)\|_\infty<\epsilon$ on $C(X)$ for $n,m\ge N$.

By Hahn-Banach, there is a functional $\phi$ with norm one such that $\phi(f_n-f_m)=\|f_n-f_m\|$, assuming $f_n\neq f_M$. But then we know $\|f_n-f_m\|=|\beta(f_n)(\phi)-\beta(f_m)(\phi)|<\epsilon$. It follows the sequence is Cauchy and indeed there is $f\in B$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$.